# Libgdx set image size

Tags: libgdx

I have Image placed in Table cell.
Image is created from TextureRegion with size 128x128
How can I scale down Image to have size 100x100. And will table cell automatically get the same size, as Image?

Comment: `table.add(image).width(100).height(100);`

Comment: I need "table cell automatically get the same size, as Image"

Answer (score 0):

Call `setSize(100, 100)` on the Image actor. The Table cell will automatically change its size, too.